# auto import all sub modules in a folder then invoke same name functions - python runtime inspect related

Tags: python, module, import, autorun, inspect

I have an open folder on my computer,

```
OpenFunctions\
    ____Template.py
    function1.py
    function2.py
    ......
    functionx.py
```

This folder is experimental purpose for extend the ability of the whole app can doing. So let’s just think it is a quick and dry trying, no security consideration in this case.

My purpose is, if I drop a `functionx.py` following the `____Template.py`, the app can know the new functions is available and will invoke the functions defined in this new joined file in someway – something like the plugin system, but should be a bit different.

So I wrote a `____inspect.py` may let application have an ability to know what has been inputed.

Here is the

```
____inspect.py

def get_this_file_defined_functions(name_filter = "__"):
    import inspect, sys 
    f = inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], inspect.isfunction) 
    return [x for x in f if not x[0].startswith(name_filter)] 

def get_this_module_sub_modules(name_filter = "__"):
    import os.path, pkgutil
    pkgpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    m = [name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules([pkgpath])] 
    return [x for x in m if not x[0].startswith(name_filter)]

def import_sub_modules_under_me(auto_exec_function = "auto_exec"):
    m = get_this_module_sub_modules()
    for i in m:  # need try except later
        exec "global %s; import %s" % (i, i)  
        #this will auto invoke __init__.py if sub modules folder is included
    for i in m:
        try:
            eval(i).eval(auto_exec_function)()
        except AttributeError:
            print "module %s has no function %s", % (i, auto_exec_function) 
        else:
            print "error on execute %s in module %s", % (auto_exec_function, i)

def execute_all_homonymy_functions(exec_function = "exec"):
    m = get_this_module_sub_modules()
    for i in m:
        #I need here for test if the module has been imported
        eval(i).eval(exec_function)()
```

Here is the

```
____Template.py

def __you_can_not_see_me(): pass  # because filtered by str.startswith()
def auto_exec(): pass             # this will be auto executed
def you_can_get_me(): pass
def you_can_get_me1(): pass
def you_can_get_me2(): pass
```

based on above idea I also want to extend structure to below

```
main.py
____inspect.py
OpenFunctions\
    __init__.py
    ____Template.py
    function1.py
    function2.py
    ......
    functionx.py
    module_aa
        \__init__.py
          aa.py
          aa1.py
```

Here is the `main.py` while the `__init__.py` may looks like

```
import ____inspect
____inspect.import_sub_modules_under_me()
____inspect.execute_all_homonymy_functions("what_ever_i_want")
```

**Questions:**

1. Above `__init__` code will not working, because the `sys.modules[__name__]` is `____inspect` when invoking but not the 
   `OpenFunctions` or `module_aa` I want, is there a way to avoid pass the `sys.modules[__name__]` to the `import_sub_modules_under_me()` on the  `main.py` or the `__init__.py`?
2. I suppose `execute_all_homonymy_functions()` will execute all the same name function in folder no matter it is exists in a sub module or in a single file, but I want to invoke all and the latest version in case the module new added or the source has been changed runtime. Then I want to use the code `import aa, reload(aa)` but may be thought as the wrong on below link, any suggestions? 
   The issue I marked `I need here for test if the module has been imported` in *_*_inspect.py

   [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027352/how-to-test-if-one-python-module-has-been-imported]
3. I also want to know the return type of one function in a file before invoking it, it was suggested to attach a decorate on each function. So my plan is:

\n

```
____decorate.py

def attrs(**kwds):
     def decorate(f):
         for k in kwds:
             setattr(f, k, kwds[k])
         return f
     return decorate

functionx.py
import ../____decorate.py

@attrs(argument_types=(int, int,),returns=int)
def __you_can_not_see_me(): pass

@attrs(argument_types=(int, int,),returns=int)
def auto_exec(): pass             # I will be auto executed

@attrs(argument_types=(int, int,),returns=int)
def you_can_get_me(): pass

@attrs(argument_types=(int, int,),returns=int)
def you_can_get_me1(): pass

@attrs(argument_types=(int, int,),returns=int)
def you_can_get_me2(): pass
```

Is it works ok for inspect case? Or there’s an better solution?

The last one:  below code

```
exec "global %s; import %s" % (i, i) 
eval(i).eval(auto_exec_function)()
```

looks ugly, any alternative for above two lines?

Thanks for your help.

Rgs, 
KC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your last question first: to dynamically import modules in recent versions of Python, use `importlib.import_module()`, that's what it is for. If you're on an older version of Python, you should use `__import__` instead (but check the idiosyncracies of that direct approach in the docs - there's a reason the `import_module()` function was added as a replacement).

To address your first question: there is no officially portable way to retrieve information about the calling function's global environment, so the most correct answer is to simply pass `__name__` in as an argument wherever it is needed.

Reloading in Python is always a little dangerous, since not everything works correctly under reloading (even many standard library modules will fail if you reload either them, or a module they reference).

I really suggest spending some time exploring the answers to this existing question about plugin architectures in Python: [Building a minimal plugin architecture in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932069/building-a-minimal-plugin-architecture-in-python)

Comment: thanks for reply, I've read serval plugin module before, but I found one common problem for me is those plugin system may like a class - you have to define plugins following the strict template. for most system it is ok, but for me to finish those dirty works, it is not worth for me to write those special designed code. thanks again for your suggestion

Comment: and dirty just means one-off here, sorry for my english.