# How do I load and run specific packages when I launch 'matplotlib'?

Tags: python, configuration, matplotlib

I see how to change certain settings for `matplotlib` in such a way that the are used to configure it each time I launch, including when I launch interactively with

```
ipython --pylab
```

but I'm not sure how run arbitrary code each time I launch in this way, or how to ensure that certain packages have been imported. For example I'd like to do the following whenever I launch as above:

```
from mpltools import style
style.use('ggplot')
```

How do I load and run specific packages when I launch 'matplotlib'?

Comment: Are you asking how to have `ipython` automatically do it (easy to set up) or how to do it in general for any library?  (Doing this in a general sense is discouraged. "Explicit is better than implicit" It's better to just explicitly change the style with `mpltools`.)  Also, the next version of `matplotlib` will have `mpltools` stylesheets built in and (I think?) an option for this in the .matplotlibrc.

Comment: I'm mostly asking how to do the specific steps in the example: set a  style as the default for `ipython --pylab`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the ipython [website](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/overview.html#startup-files) it seems you can place any `.py` file in the `startup` folder of your profile and it will be run when ipython is initiated. For help finding the profile where your startup folder is [see here].

To get the effect your looking for you need to check that matplotlib has been imported, the only way I can think of doing that is to add the following

```
import sys

if "matplotlib" in sys.modules:
   # Do something 
   print
   print "This seems to be working"
```

I have left it with the test so you can quickly determine if it is working.
Two things to note: I am using ipython 2.0.0-dev (in case this has any bearing), and secondly I suspect that calling `sys.modules` is not recommended, or at least that was the impression I had off the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027352/how-to-test-if-one-python-module-has-been-imported) post I borrowed the idea from, perhaps someone better than I can enlighten us.

Comment: I could avoid the check if instead of supplying `--pylab` I was able to put code that has the same effect in something like a startup `.py` that I could select as a command line argument to `ipython` (e.g. `ipython --profile='my_configured_pylab`). Is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: Yes, [in this link](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.2/html/config/customization.html) it claims you just place `ipy_profile_<name>.py` in your current directory or your IPYTHONDIR then load with `--profile <name>`. I think that is probably what you need.

Comment: Excellent. So the only remaining question is: What lines of code in such a file would have the effect of the `--pylab` flag?

Comment: `from matplotlib.pylab import * ` I would assume. This will pull in all the modules. If anything is missing just locate it and add it.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do the trick: [a separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20252855/656912).