# How can I recreate the effect of IPython's '--pylab' option with a script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, matplotlib, ipython

I'd like to create a profile that does the same thing as IPython's `--pylab` flag "by hand". What should the contents of a script be — package imports, namespace designations, settings, etc. — to achieve this?

As an alternative, I'd also be interested in whether there is a way to check that the `--pylab` flag was set when the current IPython session was launched.

---

Simply doing `from matplotlib.pylab import *` doesn't work, nor does `%pylab` (since magics don't seem to be allowed in profiles).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Digging into the help and man pages (`$ ipython --help-all` then followed by a search for "pylab") reveals:

```
--pylab=<CaselessStrEnum> (InteractiveShellApp.pylab) # mean is an alias for

--InteractiveShellApp.pylab=<CaselessStrEnum>
    Default: None
    Choices: ['auto', 'gtk', 'inline', 'osx', 'qt', 'qt4', 'tk', 'wx']
    Pre-load matplotlib and numpy for interactive use, selecting a particular
    matplotlib backend and loop integration.
--InteractiveShellApp.pylab_import_all=<Bool>
    Default: True
    If true, IPython will populate the user namespace with numpy, pylab, etc.
    and an ``import *`` is done from numpy and pylab, when using pylab mode.
    When False, pylab mode should not import any names into the user namespace.
```

So `c.InteractiveShellApp.pylab='auto'` in whatever [configuration](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/overview.html#configuration-objects-and-files) or [profile](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/overview.html#profiles) you are loading will do the trick.

(Agreed with Andrew that hiding like this is unpythonic.)

Answer (score 3):

In an ipython sense, you can do this by creating a new iPython profile

```
ipython profile create <name>
```

Edit the ipython_config.py directory. On newer installs of ipython under linux, this file will be in `~/.config/ipython/profile_<name>` directory, but you can find it if you're unsure with:

```
ipython profile locate <name>
```

For me, I can I edit the appropriate file with the bash command:

```
vim `ipython profile locate <name>`/ipython_config.py
```

Edit the appropriate variables in that file (see the ipython docs).

---

In a more general sense, you can force python to run arbitrary code at startup by setting the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable, and pointing it at a python file with commands in it. To be equivalent to `--pylab` that file would need to have the following contents (equivalent to ipython 1.1).

```
# See: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.1.0/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.pylab.html
import numpy
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pylab, mlab, pyplot
np = numpy
plt = pyplot

from IPython.display import display
from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize, getfigs

from pylab import *
from numpy import *
```

From past experience setting your `PYTHONSTARTUP` variable *is probably a bad idea*. All your Python code must have an x-session (or equivalent), unless you're setting a backend that doesn't pop up a plot window. It also pollutes the global namespace for everything you run and will slow down the interpreter (matplotlib in particular takes a noticeable amount of time to import on my machines).

Comment: Is it any slower or more polluting than using the `--pylab` flag? Also, those lines don't seem to be sufficient to mimic the `--pylab` flag (e.g. [`x = randn(10000)`](http://matplotlib.org) gives "NameError: name 'randn' is not defined").

Comment: With respect to this being more polluting than --pylab? No it isn't. But it's also far less visible (from the zen of python "Explicit is better than implicit")

Comment: I've fixed the list of imports - it still isn't perfect, but under normal circumstances, the differences should be negligible.

Comment: Yes, I get that it's unpythonic. It's just for convenience, but I see why it's a bad habit too.