# How do you import a Python library within an R package using rPython?

Tags: python, r, roxygen2, rpython

The basic question is this: Let's say I was writing R functions which called python via `rPython`, and I want to integrate this into a package. That's simple---it's irrelevant that the R function wraps around Python, and you proceed as usual. e.g.

```
# trivial example
# library(rPython)
add <- function(x, y) {
  python.assign("x", x)
  python.assign("y", y)
  python.exec("result = x+y")
  result <- python.get("result")
  return(result)
}
```

But what if the python code with R functions *require* users to import Python libraries first? e.g.

```
# python code, not R
import numpy as np
print(np.sin(np.deg2rad(90)))

# R function that call Python via rPython
# *this function will not run without first executing `import numpy as np`
print_sin <- function(degree){
   python.assign("degree", degree)
   python.exec('result = np.sin(np.deg2rad(degree))')
   result <- python.get('result')
   return(result)
}
```

If you run this without importing the library `numpy`, you will get an error.

How do you import a Python library in an R package? How do you comment it with `roxygen2`?

It appears the R standard is this:

```
# R function that call Python via rPython
# *this function will not run without first executing `import numpy as np`
print_sin <- function(degree){
   python.assign("degree", degree)
   python.exec('import numpy as np')
   python.exec('result = np.sin(np.deg2rad(degree))')
   result <- python.get('result')
   return(result)
}
```

Each time you run an R function, you will import an entire Python library.

Comment: I'm confused by this whole series of questions. I've literally never used rPython, but just scanning the documentation I don't quite understand why you wouldn't simply call `python.exec("import numpy as np")` inside the function itself first?

Comment: Its not ridiculous. "Importing an entire python library" twice is not a problem.  Most python codes could have `import sys` in a hundred places. Having an `import` for every function is a good example of "explicit is better than implicit". Or have an R `.First` in your package that imports all your python libs, but then you have to keep that up to date but thats probably a false optimisation.

Comment: @Spacedman Well, if you insist. Python maintains an internal list of all modules that have been imported. "Most python codes could have import sys in a hundred places." But they don't. Just as R libraries are not loaded with R functions, it's weird to load python libraries in functions. It also hits your performance, I would think. The second idea is probably better, to use `.First`

Comment: `.First` is for sessions; you want `.onLoad` / `.onAttach` for a package.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang , actually a fairly standard idiom in R functions is `if (require("packagename")) { ... } `

Comment: Most python *modules* may only have one `import sys` but every module that needs `sys` will have `import sys`, so in a complex system of connected modules there could be lots of `import sys` going on. Please show some benchmarks to support your performance claim. A loop around `import numpy as np` should do it.

Comment: @Spacedman https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Import_Statement_Overhead

Comment: @ShanZhengYang enjoy your 7/100000 of a second you save every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Spacedman and @DirkEddelbuettel suggest you could add a `.onLoad`/`.onAttach` function to your package that calls `python.exec` to import the modules that will typically always be required by users of your package.

You could also [test whether the module has already been imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027352/how-to-test-if-one-python-module-has-been-imported) before importing it, but (a) that gets you into a bit of a regression problem because you need to import `sys` in order to perform the test, (b) the answers to that question suggest that at least in terms of performance, it shouldn't matter, e.g.

> If you want to optimize by not importing things twice, save yourself the hassle because Python already takes care of this.

(although admittedly there is some <s>quibbling</s>discussion elsewhere on that page about possible scenarios where there could be a performance cost). 
But maybe your concern is stylistic rather than performance-oriented ...

Comment: Thanks for this! There is some mention of a performance overhead on that page, but I might just bite the bullet and write it into the R function. The motivation for asking this question was originally to find out what the "standard" was, and I think we've covered this. I appreciate the help! Thank you!